# Pagination Library on an Add-on Control Panel Page

Tags: control-panel, pagination

I am updating the Link Vault add-on to paginate the report results in the control panel. For some reason, the link generated for the page 1 link always leaves off the defined suffix of query string parameters. Has anyone experienced this before? How do I fix it?

I verified that the $query_string_suffix variable is populated correctly. It must be since all the other pagination links are fine. It is just the page 1 or "first" link that is wrong. Why would all the others be fine?

```
// Setup the pagination links
$page_config = array(
    'base_url'          => $this->base_url.AMP.'method=reports',
    'total_rows'        => count($complete_report_data),
    'per_page'          => $data['limit'],
    'page_query_string' => true,
    'suffix'            => $query_string_suffix
);
```

Edit: I found [this bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19272) from EE 2.5.5 but the known solution doesn't seem to describe code that is still located in the Pagination library.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the module?

```
$base_url = 'C=addons_modules' . AMP . 'M=show_module_cp' . AMP . 'module=scheduled_trigger';
$root_url = BASE . AMP . $base_url;
$method_url = $root_url . AMP . 'method=';
```

Copied from [Scheduled trigger, settings form](https://github.com/caddis/scheduled-trigger/blob/master/system/expressionengine/third_party/scheduled_trigger/ext.scheduled_trigger.php) the syntax changed slightly.

Edit: see also module tutorial, pagination is mentioned
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html

Note to self: control panel links can/should be made with cp_url() (EE 2.8+)
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_styles/index.html#cp-internal-links